# How can I add the same variable multiple times in python?

Tags: python

This is my code (Python 3.2)

```
Total = eval(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
#say the user enters 3
for i in range(Total):
    Numbers = input("Please enter a number ")
#User enters in 1
#User enters in 2
#User enters in 3
print ("The sum of the numbers you entered is", Numbers)
#It displays 3 instead of 6
```

How do i get it to add up properly?

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick and dirty rewrite of your lines:

```
Total = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
#say the user enters 3
Numbers=[]
for i in range(Total):
    Numbers.append(int(input("Please enter a number "))
#User enters in 1
#User enters in 2
#User enters in 3
print ("The sum of the numbers you entered is", sum(Numbers))
#It displays 3 instead of 6
```

I assume that you use Python 3 because of the way you `print`, but if you use Python 2 use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Just letting you know, I edited your answer before I realised it was merely reflecting the question. Not cool. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This code will fix your problem:

```
total = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
#say the user enters 3
sum_input = 0
for i in range(total):
    sum_input += int(input("Please enter a number "))
#User enters in 1
#User enters in 2
#User enters in 3
print ("The sum of the numbers you entered are", sum_input)
```

---

A number of comments:

1. You should stick to [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for styling and variable names. Specifically, use `under_store` for variable names and function names, and `CapWords` for class names.
2. The use of `eval` is questionable here. [This article](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/) explains very well on why you shouldn't use `eval`  in [most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Reusing `total` is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable outside the for loop, and keep on adding input numbers to it in the loop..

```
numbers = 0
for i in range(Total):
    numbers += int(input("Please enter a number "))

print ("The sum of the numbers you entered are", numbers)
```